# Compatible Visual Stuido hotkeys with OBS?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, obs

Sorry this is a really stupid question:

I'm recording a video of something I'm working on in visual studio and I was wondering if there are any 'safe' (by default not used) hotkeys to use for recording start / stop.

I've always used f10, but that's build/run for VisualStudio.

Alternatively... is it simpler / advisable to just change the VS hotkey or disable it all together? (I don't mind clicking the little button).

Is there any 'professional' philosophy or best practices when it comes to hotkey conflicts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view/search/rebind Visual Studio hotkeys in menu:Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard.

If you want a hotkey that is *definitely* not being listened to by any software, on Windows any keyboard buttons (such as less-commonly-used Right Alt, Scroll Lock, media buttons on some keyboards, etc.) can be rebound to F13..F24 using registry or software (such as SharpKeys)

Comment: Thank you I am looking through the shortcuts already, but there's a ton of entries. Do you know anything off the top of your head that isn't used or I won't miss a shortcut for in VS?

Comment: You can check if a shortcut is in use by clicking on "Press shortcut keys:" field, pressing a combination, and then checking if "Currently used by" shows anything. On my installation, Alt+F1 is not taken, but I'm not sure if that's the default or if I have unbound it.